# Discord.py bot - how to make bot copy the last message

Tags: python, discord, command, bots

I'm developing in Python. I'd like to make my bot copying the previous message

For example, i type the command !copy So it would look like this:

**User 1**: Sup

**User 2**: !copy

**Bot**: The message has been saved

**User 1**: idk

**User 2**: !paste

**Bot**: User 1 say: Sup

i try this

```
@commands.command(name='copy')
async def copiar_ultimo_mensaje(self, ctx):
    # Obtener el contenido del portapapeles del usuario
    contenido = self.portapapeles.get(ctx.author.id)
    if contenido:
        # Enviar el contenido al usuario que ejecutó el comando
        await ctx.send(f'¡Mensaje copiado!\n{contenido}')
    else:
        await ctx.send('No hay mensajes en el portapapeles.')

@commands.command(name='paste')
async def pegar_ultimo_mensaje(self, ctx):
    # Obtener el contenido del portapapeles del usuario
    contenido = self.portapapeles.get(ctx.author.id)
    if contenido:
        # Enviar el contenido de nuevo al mismo canal
        await ctx.send(self.portapapeles)
    else:
        await ctx.send('No hay mensajes en el portapapeles.')
```

but when I put !paste it gives me the last message I had written, not the saved one